# Bash conditions unclear to me

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have a problem with bash conditions especially in "if" constructions.
There is my example of if condition:

```
while [[ $BUT_O1 -eq false && $BUT_O2 -eq false && $BUT_O3 -eq false ]]
do
...
done
```

I need that cycle to stop when one of the variables comes true.

P.S. I read bash scripting how to but its still unclear for me. I even dont' understand why 0=true , when in the most languages 1=true.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you shuld place the logical operators outside tests
`[[ $BUT_O1 -eq false ]] && [[ $BUT_O2 -eq false ]] && [[ $BUT_O3 -eq false ]]`

Comment: 0 is false and 1 is true in `bash`, just like other languages. However, in most situations `bash` does not care about Boolean values, but whether or not a command succeeds (exit status 0) or fails (exit status non-zero). The confusion stems from the fact that `[[ ... ]]` succeeds  if it contains a true expression. `while` does not take a Boolean expression; it takes a command and continues while that command succeeds.

Comment: @Oberix There's no need to do that. You write code like that with `[ ... ]` because it doesn't have AND/OR operators (and I'm not counting `-a` and `-o`, which aren't fully standard and are not recommended for use). With `[[ ... ]]`, there is no reason not to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're doing arithmetic, 0 is false and nonzero is true, just like in other languages:

```
if (( 0 )); then
  echo "0 is true"
else
  echo "0 is false"
fi
# => 0 is false
```

But the normal shell "Boolean expression" (as used by `if`, `while`, etc.) doesn't operate on numbers; it operates on commands.  The shell runs the command, and if the command succeeds, then that counts as true; if the command fails, that counts as false. (In the above example, `((` is a command that returns success if the numeric value of the expression given to it is nonzero.)

Commands signal whether or not they succeed back to the shell with a one-byte "exit code" value.  In that case, 0 means success and nonzero means failure - because there's usually only one way for the command to succeed, but many ways it can go wrong. So a program can use its exit code to tell the shell not just *that* it failed, but also specifically *how* it failed. (The specific number doesn't affect the Boolean value, which is still false, but the exit code is also available as a number in `$?`, so a script is free to examine it.)

On to your code.  You're using `-eq`, which does a numeric comparison, but `false` is not a number (unless you create a variable named `false` with a numeric value). In a numeric expression like `-eq`, non-numeric strings are all treated as 0.  I suspect that you are at some point setting your variables to `true` - which is still not a number and so still treated as 0 by `-eq`.  That is:

```
if [[ true -eq false ]]; then
  echo "Whoa."
fi
# => Whoa.
```

My best guess is that you probably want something more like this:

```
declare -i BUT_01=0 BUT_02=0 BUT_03=0
while (( !BUT_O1 && !BUT_O2 && !BUT_O3 )); do
    ....
    if # we're done with BUT_01
    then
      BUT_01=1
    fi
    ... # and so on for the others
done
```

Or you may prefer the DeMorgan'ed version:

```
while (( ! (BUT_01 || BUT_02 || BUT03) )); do
```

Either way, instead of the words `true` and `false`, which are simply strings, use the numeric values `1` and `0`. If you really want to use the symbolic names, you can predeclare them:

```
declare -i false=0 true=1
```

I think you may have been thrown off by the existence of the *commands* `true` and `false`. But command names are are still just strings to the shell.  If you do this:

```
if true; then
```

the shell sees the string `"true"`, but it sees it in a place where it is looking for a command to run.  So it runs that command, which does nothing but exit immediately with exit code 0 (success).  The same goes for `false`, except it exits with a nonzero code (specifically 1).

Comment: No need to use `let` here; `false=0 true=1` has the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, at least in any externally verifiable way. `declare -p` shows the same output for variables assigned with and without `let`.